Why did David Lewis believe that all possible worlds exist?

But his largest contributions were in metaphysics. One branch of his
metaphysics was his Hume-inspired reductionism about the nomological.
He developed a position he called “Humean supervenience”, the theory
that said that there was nothing to reality except the spatio-temporal
distribution of local natural properties. And he did this by showing
in detail how laws, chances, counterfactual dependence, causation,
dispositions and colours could be located within this Humean mosaic.
The other branch of his metaphysics was his modal realism. Lewis held
that the best theory of modality posited concrete possible worlds. A
proposition is possible if and only if it is true at one of these
worlds. Lewis defended this view in his most significant book, On the
Plurality of Worlds. Alongside this, Lewis developed a new account of
how to think about modal properties of individuals, namely counterpart
theory, and showed how this theory resolved several long-standing
puzzles about modal properties.

David Lewis
What argument led Lewis to believe that the hypothetical possible worlds referred to in modal logics necessarily actually exist?

Relevant but doesn’t answer my question clearly or directly enough: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/for-the-modal-realist-do-possible-individuals-and-worlds-exist-necessarily

From western philosophy perspective for your interest, modal realism just follows the good old 'principle of plenitude' since Plato which is the contrary of the more famous Occam's razor 'principle of parsimony', Lovejoy traces this principle to the writings of Plato, finding in the Timaeus an insistence on "the necessarily complete translation of all the ideal possibilities into actuality"...

The SEP's entry on Lewis you are quoting refers to David Lewis's On the Plurality of Worlds (1986): "Lewis proposes that possible worlds, including ours, are real concrete things that are isolated from each other. "There are no spatiotemporal relations at all between things that belong to different worlds," and adds, "Nor does anything that happens at one world cause anything to happen at another." 1/2

He recommends a plurality of worlds because hypothesizing it is "serviceable," the familiar analysis of necessity as truth at all possible worlds being "only the beginning." Lewis shows that modal realism can be used to give coherent accounts of, among other things, modal logic and counterfactual conditionals. " 2/2

Regarding DoubleKnot's comment above, see Principle of plenitude and Modal realism.
